# ChangeDisplaySettingsEx change screen order

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I'm wrote the following program that flips every screen of the computer:

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    DISPLAY_DEVICE device;
    device.cb = sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE);

    for (DWORD i = 0; EnumDisplayDevices(NULL, i, &device, 0); i++)
    {
        DEVMODE dm;
        dm.dmSize = sizeof(DEVMODE);
        if (EnumDisplaySettings(NULL, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, &dm) == 0)
            continue;

        dm.dmDisplayOrientation = DMDO_180;

        ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(device.DeviceName, &dm, NULL, CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY, NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It works well but its change the order of my three screens. Before the execution, the order is (from left to right) 3 - 2 - 1 and after, 2 - 1 - 3.

Is there a way to preserve to change the display settings without altering my screen order ?

Thanks

Comment: 1. Did you follow the instructions for EnumDisplaySettings - the one where it says you have to set dmSize? 2. Did you follow the instructions for ChangeDisplaySettingsEx regarding dmSize and dmDriverExtra and dmFields?

Comment: Hello, I've indeed forgot to init of dm.dmSize before calling EnumDisplaySettings. It did not change the behaviour of the code regarding the my code. This field was filled by EnumDisplaySettings any way. Regarding ChangeDisplaySettingsEx, EnumDisplayDevice fill the DEVMODE with (among others) the required fields.

Comment: Which fields are required?

Comment: Did you read that dmFields is required?

Comment: `EnumDisplaySettings` will enumerate the screens in order, do you mean that after the application runs, `ChangeDisplaySettingsEx` does not flip in the order of the default 3-2-1?